# Dreamweaver CS5 temp files?

Tags: dreamweaver, flash-cs5

Sometimes Dreamweaver CS5 creates this: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/419629/tempfiles.jpg
strange temp files, where can i turn it off? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

YOu don't show the full file name of the temp file you refer to, but Dreamweaver has a Preview In Browser option that creates temp files, typically with random characters starting with TMP, but I've not used that feature in quite a while. If this is the issue you're having go to:

Edit (Dreamweaver on Mac) -> Preferences. Select "Preview in Browser" category on the left, and uncheck the "Preview using temporary file".

Comment: Thanks, the "Preview using temporary file" is unchecked, maybe it´s another strange preference selected - but i can´t find out :-)